# Getting empty collection while fetching the users from outlook with EWS

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, nullreferenceexception

Getting empty collection while fetching the users from outlook. Maybe someone is familiar with the issue.

This is how I set up my exchange service. This is pretty standard and followed the documentation in Microsoft:

```
exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(SMTPClientFactory.Secret());
exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "example@com");
exchangeService.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "example@com");
```

Of course I used the address that has shared mailbox.

I have to use EWS to fetch users from outlook but keep going to the dead end. I tried to use function

```
var allUsers = exchangeService.ResolveName("SMTP:", ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsThenDirectory, true);
```

But this function has the limitation and it cannot fetch more than 100 users.

I also tried to use this code

```
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ContactSchema.EmailAddress1, "@");
// Use a FindPeopleResults object to retrieve the contacts.
FindPeopleResults results = exchangeService.FindPeople(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, searchFilter, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)).Result;
```

But this does not fetch anything. Also tried to use `FindItem` function it is also does not get me anything.

The goal is to use fetch all users.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Item item in results.Items)
{
    EmailAddress user = item as EmailAddress;
    if (user != null)
    {
        NameResolutionCollection resolutions = service.ResolveName(user.Address, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true);
        foreach (NameResolution resolution in resolutions)
        {
            Contact contact = resolution.Contact;
            if (contact != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(contact.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this type of thing

```
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactSchema.EmailAddress1, "*");
FindPeopleResults results = exchangeService.FindPeople(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, searchFilter, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)).Result;
```

will not work in EWS as the FindPeople operation doesn't support searchFilters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findpeople-operation . The way they implemented FindPeople in the Managed API isn't correct the only search restriction supported is an AQS querystring so

```
FindPeopleResults results = exchangeService.FindPeople(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, "SMTP:", new ItemView(int.MaxValue)).Result
```

should work but int.MaxValue won't do anything EWS will at best page back the result 100 items at a time.

It looks like you are using Office365 so EWS is the not the best endpoint to be using for this. Eg if you just use the Graph and an Advanced query you can get all the directory objects much faster https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=proxyAddresses/any (p:startswith(p, 'SMTP:'))&$select=id,displayName,proxyaddresses,mailNickname,userType&$top=999
```

If your trying build Outlook type functionality the search endpoint is what you should be using as this is where all the new features and functionality is being enabled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-person